# IIS 7.5 Does Not Reset

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Setup: Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5

We currently have multiple ASP.NET applications hooked up to the "Default Web Site" site in IIS on a server.

- Sites

  - Default Web Site

    - aspnet_client
    - Site_v1
    - Site_v2
    - Site_v3

I have recompiled the binary for the site, and copied over the files for "Site_v1", then done an IISRESET command.

My issue is that the web app does *not* actually reset.  Our app logs initialization of certain core objects, and the logs do not show that the app is restarting.

Our current theory is that some user has a browser open to one of the default web sites, and that's preventing me from correctly resetting IIS.

Anyone seen anything like this?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm posting this to Stack Overflow and not Super User because this is a problem on a development server.  I'd like to solve this as a developer correctly compiling an application, rather than as a sys admin changing server settings.  Hope that makes sense.

UPDATE:

From Werner's suggestion in the comments, I deleted the temporary files for Site_v2, but could not delete them for Site_v1.  Some process was locking the files.  After resetting IIS, Site_v1 was working properly, but not Site_v2.

Superconfused!

Comment: I have encountered something similiar before. You may want to stop IIS (iisreset /stop), delete the ASP.NET Temporary Files, and start IIS (iisreset). You didn't specify which version of .NET you are using, but the temporary files should be here: %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: @WernerStrydom Ah, good point.  It's 3.5.

Comment: Delete the temporary files located at `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and see if that sorts your problem. This should automatically be taken care of when you create a new web application during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

MS have stopped support for the IISReset command, which means that your approach is OK, but will not work any more. It works for IIS6.0, but not 7.0 or 7.5.

Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd364308%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

It can be done "by hand" using the GUI, but that is not scripted. I have the same issue, working on an alternative.